# ¿de que forma puedo realizar una resta en c# mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

no se de que forma podre realizar una resta de dos columnas entre stock y fisico(fisico corresponde a cantidad tambien pero del inventario), no se si se hara aca en el index.cshtml o en el controlador, la realize un pequeño ejemplo de sacar resta pero solo me da los dos numeros de las dos tablas, que indique,
Para si me pueden ayudar o algun ejemplo a seguir, para responder a mi consulta en este caso, se agradece:)

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Codigo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Articulo1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Modelo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stock)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.inventario.Fisico)
        </th>
        <th>
            Diferencia
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrecioUnitario)
        </th>
        <th>
            Total
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codigo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Articulo1)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Modelo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.inventario.Fisico)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock)-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.inventario.Fisico)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrecioUnitario)
    </td>
    <td>
        holl
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Codigo }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Codigo }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Codigo })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

aca esta mi clase controlador, no se si se hace la logica en este lado controlador

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using proyectoFinal_Web.Models;

namespace proyectoFinal_Web.Controllers
{
    public class articuloesInventarioController : Controller
    {
        private bdTiendaEntities db = new bdTiendaEntities();

        // GET: articuloesInventario
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var articulo = db.articulo.Include(a => a.inventario).Include(a => a.marca1);
            return View(articulo.ToList());
        }

        // GET: articuloesInventario/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            articulo articulo = db.articulo.Find(id);
            if (articulo == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(articulo);
        }

        // GET: articuloesInventario/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Codigo = new SelectList(db.inventario, "Codigo", "Codigo");
            ViewBag.Marca = new SelectList(db.marca, "Codigo", "Nombre");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: articuloesInventario/Create
        // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que quiere enlazarse. Para obtener 
        // más detalles, vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Codigo,Articulo1,Descripcion,Modelo,Marca,Stock,PrecioUnitario")] articulo articulo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.articulo.Add(articulo);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Codigo = new SelectList(db.inventario, "Codigo", "Codigo", articulo.Codigo);
            ViewBag.Marca = new SelectList(db.marca, "Codigo", "Nombre", articulo.Marca);
            return View(articulo);
        }

        // GET: articuloesInventario/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            articulo articulo = db.articulo.Find(id);
            if (articulo == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Codigo = new SelectList(db.inventario, "Codigo", "Codigo", articulo.Codigo);
            ViewBag.Marca = new SelectList(db.marca, "Codigo", "Nombre", articulo.Marca);
            return View(articulo);
        }

        // POST: articuloesInventario/Edit/5
        // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que quiere enlazarse. Para obtener 
        // más detalles, vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Codigo,Articulo1,Descripcion,Modelo,Marca,Stock,PrecioUnitario")] articulo articulo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(articulo).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Codigo = new SelectList(db.inventario, "Codigo", "Codigo", articulo.Codigo);
            ViewBag.Marca = new SelectList(db.marca, "Codigo", "Nombre", articulo.Marca);
            return View(articulo);
        }

        // GET: articuloesInventario/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            articulo articulo = db.articulo.Find(id);
            if (articulo == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(articulo);
        }

        // POST: articuloesInventario/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            articulo articulo = db.articulo.Find(id);
            db.articulo.Remove(articulo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Cualquier tipo de lógica de negocio no se debe realizar en la vista.

Lo que podrías hacer es extender el modelo de Articulo mediante una Partial Class (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) y ahi resolver el calculo:

```
public partial class Articulo
    {
        public string Diferencia
        {
            get
            {
                return Math.Max(0,this.Stock - this.Iventario);
            }
        }}
```

Comment: dale pa gracias, realice todo lo equivocada en vistas cree la logica de negocio que no es correcto, gracias  pa,

Comment: y para saber, tambien si las restas me den negativas, solamente me den sin el signo negativo, se aplica el if?

Comment: Ahi lo modifique, esa funcion te devuelve el mayor numero de los que le estas pasando como parametro: en el caso de darte negativo, te devolveria 0. Otra alternativa es hacerlo con un if inline..

Comment: en caso de que las restas sean 14-16 = -2, lo cual me daria 0 en ese caso pero, en ese caso sacar solamente el signo(-)  para que de total 2 positivo(+)

Comment: con un if inline?

Comment: "Inline if" seria algo asi: (condition ? [true value] : [false value]).  Para el caso que nombras de convertir el -2 en 2.... se hace con la funcion Math.ABS([number])

Comment: vala pa, muchas gracias!!, por la ayuda se agradece:)))